# Fopen didnt see /dev/usb/lp0

Tags: php, ubuntu, fopen

I've got a problem with open /dev/usb/lp0 . In terminal I see that file, but in PHP I dont. If i try open that file in PHP, I got error : `open(/dev/usb/lp0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` so I try `sudo chmod 777 /dev/usb` but nothing change. I try to scan /dev/ folder in PHP [Picture of all folder, what i see in PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQSJU.png). And nothing change, again.. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks, for help.

Comment: How is your server configured? You might have a `chroot` set up for it that blocks access to files outside of it's directory.

Comment: There was is problem. I just add to docker-compose.yml this:
privileged: true
    devices:
      - '/dev:/dev'

and everything is working. Thanks :)